# What are the advantages of luanching a GUI in a thread using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Hi all I have seen Swing GUI's being launch like this

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Gui();
        }

    });

}

}
```

What are the benefits of launching it this way?

Comment: Your Swing program will *usually* run just fine without this, but not 100% of the time, just most of the time. Expect it to fail when demonstrating your program to the boss or the big client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than benefits, I would say that it is necessary because most Swing components are not thread safe. `invokeLater` will run the task inside Swing event dispatch thread, avoiding thread interference or memory consistency errors.

You can find it mentioned in the [Swing Tutorial, Event Dispatch Thread chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Answer (score 4):

Swing is single threaded. You need to queue GUI changes onto the swing event dispatch thread. It isn't really an advantage, it is a requirement. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html